# "Android Asset Studio" adds extra space when I upload my .png icons, but doesn't when it uses its internal cliparts. Why?

Tags: android, android-studio, icons, android-icons

I'm trying to create some nice icons for some Android APP I'm dealing with, and someone directed me to the "Android Asset Studio", that nice online tool which creates full packs of icons ready to be deployed onto my (horridly) fragmented Android project res folder.

I just went to its URL to create my icons:

EDIT: [broken URL as of Oct 2016. Apparently everything has moved into Android Studio]
<s>http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-actionbar.html#source.type=image&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_action_stickers&theme=custom&color=000%2C80</s>

Then I noticed something a bit annoying: When using its internal cliparts, they appear perfectly trimmed/clipped/padded (that is, 0 padding), but when I try to upload my simple transparent .png files, this tool always adds some annoying padding space around my final icons, no matter what.

Is it normal? I've played with "trim/no-Trim" and "padding" buttons, but no luck (it just even makes things a bit worse).

Any hint? Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: The same happens to me with the eclipse tool, even when the 0% padding has been choosed :(

Comment: Problem is not only with on-line tool,it is happening in Android Studio also if icon generated by image asset :( :(

Comment: I found out that when selecting my custom png (which has a full size circle), and I choose "no shape", the icon is a bit smaller. 

But when I choose "circle shape" (which will not appear since it's behind my image), the icon gets the full area.

Answer (score 42):

A couple of days ago I made this:

http://reiszecke.github.io/AndroidAssetStudioFullsize/

when you choose `>> Launcher icons << Full Size edit` you will be able to get your files on full size without any padding. **I didn't do it for every shape tho**

EDIT: I need to mention again it only works for the shape `NONE`, a bit for `BEVEL` and maybe for `CIRCLE`

EDIT2: **I do not need Google's ugly hipster dogears, rounded corners or 3D-style presets. Use photoshop if you think you need to be trendy. This is why I said I did not do it for every shape. The only purpose of my mod is to save the time you would waste converting your icon into every single icon-size.** Instead of complaining, just do your own for the other shapes. The code is public, make something of it.

Comment: idk why this is getting so many downvotes within 3 days right now. I know for a fact that it works and I did this with most of my apps now and it's been a blessing to me. Whereas the answer "Just transform the icon in Photoshop" (wtf) is at +-0. I wish SO was the place it used to be. I even kept the link to the "original" source (with the padding included) so anyone could modify it on his own.

Comment: It was working fine some time ago, but now, it puts an unwanted color over the icon and it doesn't have other functionalities such as shape

Comment: I tried this and it does exactly the other options do; add unwanted mergin thus rendering smaller than usual launcher size in android studio.

Comment: I honestly don't know what you are doing differently, I just checked it again and for me it produced a pic without any margins.

Comment: Just loaded an image - default margins are applied - so for me it's also not working, or I'm doing something wrong. (Edit: at least for default settings: "Square" - "none" and "bevel" seem to work)

Comment: Thanks, man. But imho it's completely useless clone as it doesn't remove padding at square shape

Comment: This works perfect. Uploaded image (Include padding, shadows in image), selected "Don't trim", leave the rest at defaults. Awesome.

Answer (score 6):

For those like me who hates having a smaller than the others ;-)
I made a small modification to one of the Android Studio plugin jar file.

1. Download sdk-tools.jar depending on your Android studio version from here : [download link](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BwiFrbD39Bx6ZmNOc0xZLXNBMzg&usp=sharing)
2. Close Android Studio if it's running
3. Go to `<Your Android Studio folder>/plugins/android/lib`
4. **Very important : Make sure to make a copy in another folder of your original sdk-tools.jar. If not, you won't be able to update Android Studio because of the jar modification.**
5. Copy the downloaded sdk-tools.jar file to `<Your Android Studio folder>/plugins/android/lib`
6. Restart Android Studio and enjoy

Here is the result :

No Shape - Before
[image]

No Shape - After
[image]

Square - Before
[image]

Square - After
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm Having a similar problem and found a workaround fix.
So after importing a new icon, for some reason android adding a strange padding and make them icons looking small, what I've done is
1) right click on the imported icon (you need to do it on each xhdpi etc.) 
2) reveal in folder ( <-- on Mac, on Windows should be something with explorer)
3) open the icon with photoshop and press `CTRL+T` , stretch the icon to his boundaries, save it on the current file

Again, this is a workaround solution, I hope android will fix this horrible bug on their next version.

Comment: Only way that made my animation work properly too. Terrible bug and still not fixed?