# Android app icon too small

Tags: android, android-studio, icons, android-icons

I made my icons using Inkscape following the size guidelines. They looked normal sizes on couple devices. But I wanted to make the corners rounded and I used Android Studio Assets to accomplish that. Even though, the sizes are still accurate they now look smaller on the phones? What is causing that? Has anyone run into the same problems, if so how did you resolve it? I checked SO questions and answers this morning and none of them gave me solution.

Comment: what's your icon size?

Comment: I would assume that this is a transparent margin problem added to your icon.

Comment: @Distwo, sounds about right. How do I remove the margin?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have a transparent padding added by asset studio. I am not sure if there is an option to remove the padding there. Best would be to generate the appropriate sizes straight from inkscape.

See: ["Android Asset Studio" adds extra space when I upload my .png icons, but doesn't when it uses its internal cliparts. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21266493/android-asset-studio-adds-extra-space-when-i-upload-my-png-icons-but-doesnt)